# How to Make Theorems and Equations Share Numbering

Tags: equations, numbering, theorems

How do I make theorems and equations share numbering? The default numbering system goes like this:

> Theorem 1. Blah blah blah...
>
> 1=0+1 (1)
>
> Theorem 2. More blahs...
>
> Theorem 3. No more blahs...
>
> 2=1+1 (2)

The numbers in the parenthesis are equation numbers. How do you change the above into this:

> Theorem 1. Blah blah blah...
>
> 1=0+1 (2)
>
> Theorem 3. More blahs...
>
> Theorem 4. No more blahs...
>
> 2=1+1 (5)

I am using ntheorem package, but couldn't figure out how. Would I need to use a different package?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You just need to tell it to number your theorems using the equation counter.

```
\newtheorem{thm}[equation]{Theorem}
```

Now `\begin{thm}` will be numbered the same as `\begin{equation}`.

Answer (score 4):

See the [amsthm documentation](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amscls/amsthdoc.pdf). It is only a few pages long and includes a discussion of this point (as well as lots of others relating to theorem styles).

Comment: The questioner is using ntheorem, not amsthm.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using the [thmtools](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/thmtools.html) package in addition to ntheorem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[numberlike=equation]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

\begin{theorem}
Some text.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```