# How can I number my subsequent results after my theorems?

Tags: beamer, numbering

I am trying to number my theorem results after my theorem, i.e Theorem 1 followed by Result 1.1, Result 1.2,... and Theorem 2 followed by Result 2.1, Result 2.2 and so on, where the first number after "Result" is the number of the theorem the result corresponds to. I am doing this in beamer. I am using the amsthm package and my code is as follows:

```
      \theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{res}{Result}[section]
```

Thank you!

Edit: As tohec suggested, here is a working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[ labelfont={bf, color =ot}]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{esdiff}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{res}{Result}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{thm}Here lies the first theorem.\end{thm}

\begin{res}Here lies the first result from the first theorem\end{res}

\begin{res}Here lies the second result from the first theorem\end{res}

\begin{thm}Here lies the second theorem.\end{thm}

\begin{res}Here lies the first result from the second theorem\end{res}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Beamer numbers my theorems in consecutive order and my results in consecutive order, with no relation between them.
Here is what I'd like to have:

Theorem 1
Here lies the first theorem.

Result 1.1
Here lies the first result from the first theorem.

Result 1.2
Here lies the second result from the first theorem.

Theorem 2
Here lies the second theorem.

Result 2.1
Here lies the first result from the second theorem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) With that setting you'll have "Theorem 1.1" for the first theorem in the first section. Should it be "Result 1.1.1" or "Result 1.1"?

Comment: Is `\theoremstyle{theorem} \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section] \newtheorem{res}{Result}[thm]` what you seek?

Comment: Oh dear, I made a mistake. I don't want it to be numbered after the section. Is it possible to set a counter which just counts the theorems in order and which counts the results after their corresponding theorems? Also, tohecz, that does not quite work.

Comment: @Merry In that case please provide a [Minimal (non)-Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), and as well, put together an example of the desired numbering like the one in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45817/theorem-definition-lemma-problem-numbering). Without that, your problem seems not to be understandable.

Comment: Doing `\newtheorem{res}{Result}[thm]` is exactly what you need. @tohecz Please, provide the answer.

Comment: Indeed it worked! I realized that I put \begin{theorem} instead of \begin{thm} in my actual presentation code which is why it was acting up and giving me result 0.1 instead of result 1.1. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell `{res}` to be sub-numbered from `{thm}`, which is done by an optional argument added at the end of `\newtheorem`:

```
\newtheorem{res}{Result}[thm]
```

Embedded into a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[ labelfont={bf, color =ot}]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{esdiff}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{res}{Result}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{thm}Here lies the first theorem.\end{thm}

\begin{res}Here lies the first result from the first theorem\end{res}

\begin{res}Here lies the second result from the first theorem\end{res}

\begin{thm}Here lies the second theorem.\end{thm}

\begin{res}Here lies the first result from the second theorem\end{res}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```