# Problem in numbering of definitions, lemmas and theorems

Tags: numbering

I need to write definition lemmas and theorems numbering according to chapter.

Like in chapter 1, definition number is 1.1, lemma is 1.2, theorem is 1.3. But by using commands `\newtheorem{Defintion}{definition}` I got definition 1, lemma 2, theorem 3.

Any one can please give me possible way to solve out this problem?

Comment: Under the assumption that you use `\newtheorem` from `amsthm`:  `\newtheorem{Defintion}{definition}[chapter]`

Comment: This should help: [Theorem/Definition/Lemma problem — Numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45817) (potential duplicate)

Comment: Using this  amsthm: \newtheorem{Defintion}{definition}[chapter] work like definition 1.1 theorem 1.1 lemma 1.1 but i need like definition 1.1 theorem 1.2 and lemma 1.3 so please give me the possible way for this issue