# lemma numbering like 1.2.2 Lemma

Tags: numbering, theorems

definition numbering like the below output, im getting the default numbering only.

1.1 Lemma
1.2. Proposition

how to do this using in latex

coding:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{gsm-l}

\usepackage[]{weblink}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{0}

\setcounter{section}{0}

\chapter{LINEAR SPACES}

\begin{proposition}

text

\end{proposition}

 \subsection{subsection1}

text

 \begin{lemma}

text
\end{lemma}
\begin{corollary}
 text
\end{corollary}

 \subsection{subsection2}

text

\begin{remark}

 text

\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

Output:

> Linear Spaces
>
> Proposition 1.0.1. text
>
> 1.0.1. Subsection1. text
>
> lemma 1.0.2. text
>
> corollary 1.0.3. text
>
> 1.0.2. subsection2. text
>
> remark 1.0.4. text

Expected output:

> Linear Spaces
>
> 1.0.1. Proposition%its in small caps%  text
>
> 1.0.2. Subsection1%its in small caps% text
>
> 1.0.3. lemma%its in small caps%  text
>
> 1.0.4. corollary%its in small caps%  text
>
> 1.0.5. subsection2%its in small caps%. text
>
> 1.0.6. Remark%its in small caps%  text

**without using `\newtheorem` `\newenvironment` `\theoremstyle` `\renewcommand`**

**only `\newcommand` is allowed**

[weblink](http://websoftz.com/file/)

Comment: Under the assumption that this numbering represents `<section>.<subsection>.<theorem>`, use `\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\thesubsection.\arabic{theorem}}`. What about if you have a theorem (or alike) within a section that doesn't have a subsection?

Comment: Can these discussions help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45817/27635 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2160/27635

Comment: To avoid further guesswork, can you please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that shows how you define you lemmas and propositions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To dfine your theorem-like structures in a consistent way, you can use the `amsthm` package; the `\swapnumbers` option gives the numbering and then the title; to get the theorem head in small capitals, you can easily define a new style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\swapnumbers

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
  {\topsep}
  {\topsep}
  {}
  {}
  {\scshape}
  {.}
  {.5em}
  {}
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{pro}[lem]{Proposition}

\begin{document}
\section{Test section one}
\begin{lem}
Your text goes here.
\end{lem}
\begin{pro}
Your text goes here.
\end{pro}
\section{Test section two}
\begin{pro}
Your text goes here.
\end{pro}
\begin{lem}
Your text goes here.
\end{lem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

After the edit to the question, here's an option subject to the imposed constraints: no `\newtheoremstyle`, no `\renewcommand`, no `\newenvironment` (I don't quite understand why these restrictions, specially the one about not using `\newenvironment` to define environments!; also, `weblink` uses `\newtheorem` and `\theoremstyle`, so why don't you want to use those?):

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{gsm-l}
\usepackage{weblink}

\let\lemma\relax
\let\corollary\relax
\let\proposition\relax
\let\remark\relax

\newcommand\lemma{%
  \refstepcounter{subsection}%
  \par\noindent\thesubsection.~\textsc{Lemma}.\itshape}
\newcommand\corollary{%
  \refstepcounter{subsection}%
  \par\noindent\thesubsection.~\textsc{Corollary}.\itshape}
\newcommand\proposition{%
  \refstepcounter{subsection}%
  \par\noindent\thesubsection.~\textsc{Proposition}.\itshape}
\newcommand\remark{%
  \refstepcounter{subsection}%
  \par\noindent\thesubsection.~\textsc{Remark}.\itshape}

\begin{document}

\chapter{LINEAR SPACES}

\begin{proposition}
text
\end{proposition}

\subsection{Test subsection one}

text
\begin{lemma}
text
\end{lemma}
\begin{corollary} 
text 
\end{corollary}

\subsection{Test subsection two}
text
\begin{remark}
text
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hi im edited the post with MWE. can you give me an exact solution

Comment: @ravi please see my updated answer.

Comment: these are my client restrictions

Comment: @Gonzola  hi if i use weblink package means it getting error.

Comment: @ravi `weblink` is not on TeX Live. Please provide a link to this package.

Comment: @Gonzola i had attached a hyperlink to weblink file, please read question

Comment: @ravi please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Gonzola. woww. its working .. U gave me a big relief..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10307/discussion-between-ravi-and-gonzalo-medina)

Comment: but proposition is not displaying in italics , we also restricted to use \it or \textit , we need contents of proposition in italics font style.

Comment: @ravi please see my updated answer.

Comment: now its working perfectly...

Comment: can u guide me to find a symbol
i need a symbol like \neq but =| not =/.. need equal symbol with | override

Comment: @ravi since this new requirement is unrelated to the question here, the best thing to do would be to open a fresh new question.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{lem}
\newenvironment{lem}{\refstepcounter{lem}\thesection.\thelem~\textsc{Lemma}.}{\\}
\newenvironment{pro}{\refstepcounter{lem}\thesection.\thelem~\textsc{Proposition}.}{\\}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
    This is the examples\\
    \begin{lem}
        Your text go here.
    \end{lem}
    \begin{pro}
        Your text go here.
    \end{pro}
\section{Section 2}
    \begin{pro}
        Your text go here.
    \end{pro}
    \begin{lem}
        Your text go here.
    \end{lem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it your need? Try it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (or maybe I misunderstood your problem):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[subsection] % number within subsections
\newtheorem{propo}[lemma]{Proposition}% reuse number of lemma

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}{foo}\end{lemma}

\begin{propo}{bar}\end{propo}

\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{lemma}{foo}\end{lemma}
\begin{propo}{bar}\end{propo}
\begin{propo}{bar}\end{propo}
\begin{lemma}{foo}\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

Comment: its displays like preposition 0.1... but i need 0.1 Preposition

Comment: @Ravi There are no \section commands in the document. That's why the numbering is scr*wed up.